# jquery toggle works on index but not on inner pages

Tags: jquery

Ihave a jquery code like this

```
jQuery(".pull_feedback").toggle(function(){
    jQuery("#feedback").animate({left:"0px"});
    return false;
},
function(){
    jQuery("#feedback").animate({left:"-362px"});   
    return false;
});
```

this works fine on index page but not on the inner pages.Help please!

Comment: cant we write in one place that works on all pages??

Comment: try alert in inner page. is it working? 
if not, it will be case of missing jquery file or something.

Comment: Providing the URL you're working on would help. Check that the jquery code is being loaded on both home page and inner pages and that the HTML elements you're targeting have the correct classes and IDs.

Comment: The url is http://pigeontravels.com/

Answer (score 1):

On the inner page http://pigeontravels.com/contactUs.html# you're getting an error relating to this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
</script>
```

Try changing to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
</script>
```

...and see if that works.

Comment: that didnt help.sorry!!

Comment: Can you remove that script altogether from the inner pages. On the contact page at least, there is no #gallery element on the page. I'm pretty sure the issue is with the call to undefined function 'lightBox'.